# PHP shell_exec git --version is different than when logged in via SSH

Tags: php, linux, bash, git

I have a shell script `Sync.sh` on a CentOS7 server that executes a `git checkout` and then a `git pull`. Each of these commands uses the `-C <path>` option so the script can live wherever it wants. This all works fine when logged in via SSH (PuTTY) and running the script from the command line `./Sync.sh`

However, when I run this via a PHP script, it fails:

```
$CommandOutput = shell_exec( "./Sync.sh" );
```

I added a `git --version` to `Sync.sh` and found that the PHP is using git version 1.8.3, which does not include the `-C <path>` option (it was added in 1.8.5 if I remember right). However SSH's `git --version` returns 2.9.5, which explains why running `Sync.sh` fails via PHP but works fine when run via SSH.

So the questions are:

- why is PHP getting a different git version than SSH?
- how can I make PHP get the same version as SSH?

Comment: What's in `PATH`, both in PHP and SSH?

Comment: Most probably `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Both paths are the same: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin`

Comment: Looks like the problem was the shell, PHP was getting /bin/sh while SSH was /bin/bash. Going to do some testing to verify, and if correct I'll post as an answer

Comment: I was wrong - PHP's `PATH` is `/usr/bin` (not sure how I got mixed up, I think I ran the PHP script via command line which gives the wrong output as well - it's the same as running `Sync.sh` directly). Meanwhile `/usr/bin/` does have a git, and that's the 1.8.3 I've been getting. The shell used by PHP is `/bin/sh` which is probably why the `PATH` is different, and annoyingly, there appears to be no way to change it to `/bin/bash`. In addition, attempts to modify `PATH` also fail. So I threw in the towel and modified `Sync.sh` to call the correct git like so `/usr/local/bin/git`